# Dataset/Database similar to WALS in Vowel/Phonology

Tags: phonology, computational-linguistics, vowels, consonants

I am wondering if there is any database similar to The World Atlas of Language Structures (WALS)(https://wals.info/). In the case that it is specifically more geared towards phonological aspects of languages, more specifically vowels and consonants.

Comment: WALS chapters 1-19 all deal with phonology. Are you looking for something other than that? Do you want a database showing in which languages particular phonemes occur?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but I need something like that, but where almost all features are phonological area. Yes, languages with particular phonemes would be helpful, I am specifically looking for databases that have information like Uvular Consonant and Velar Nasal.

Answer (score 7):

There is the famous UPSID database: http://phonetics.linguistics.ucla.edu/sales/software.htm

Answer (score 5):

[PHOIBLE Online](https://phoible.org/) is a database compiled from sources describing various languages' phonological inventories and is searchable by language, source, or phone.